# How to rewrite this route to ini format?

Tags: zend-framework, ini, zend-controller-router

I have the following PHP code:

```
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
            'subdomain.example.com',
            array(
                'module' => 'subdomain',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action'     => 'index'
            )
        );

        $plainPathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':controller/:action/*',
            array(
                'controller'=> 'index',
                'action' => 'index'   
            )
        );

        $router->addRoute('subdomain', $hostnameRoute->chain($plainPathRoute));
```

Now I would like to have this route in my application.ini

I tried it with this code, but this is not working:

```
resources.router.routes.subdomain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.route = "subdomain.example.com"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.defaults.module = "subdomain"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.default.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.default.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.default.defaults.controller = "index"
```

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
resources.router.routes.subdomain.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.route = ":module.example.com"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.defaults.module = ""
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.index.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.index.route = ":controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.index.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.subdomain.chains.index.defaults.action = "index"
```

Try this

Comment: No specific errors, but the problem is everything goes to the 'default' module while it should go to the subdomain module

Comment: I know this is stupid question so no offense but have You change defaults module in my code?

Comment: solved partially now. I had defined somewhere a route with the same key, stupid :(. But it still works one way. If I enter subdomain.example.com in my browser everything werks perfect. But if I do $this->url(array(), 'subdomain') I get an exception with message 'Route subdomain is not defined' while it works perfect with just the plain php code